# manipulating the website action through external java code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

There is a website,and it has a button on click checks for the value in the textbox and searches for it and displays the result.
How can i with my java code,prove the input and display the appropriate result on my java code.
On seeing the source of the website,i get to know the methods that gets called on the button click.But what and how to further trigger the event and pass the value to textbox and obtain the resut !!

Comment: Are you sure this question is not about JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a programmatic web browser like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: in a particular webpage,there is a button that searches for the given text in the textbox in the database.I could manualy open that website in browser,enter the data and search the database.But how do i do the same behaviour through my java code which gets the text from the user posts it to the textbox in website and fetches the result.

Comment: Read my answer. Use HtmlUnit. Just click on the link I gave you, then click "Get started", and read the last example in this page, which does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The button in the page is in the described tags                    <fieldset><div class="row">
  <input type=submit value="Process"></fieldset>
</div> how do i identify the button in the webpage as trigger the method that it is intented to call...i dont have a button id or name.please help.thankyou !!

Comment: Have you searched in the javadoc? You have to learn reading documentation if you want to become a serious developer. Here's the javadoc for HtmlPage: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html. You can iterate through the elements having the tag name "input" (see getElementsByTagName in the documentation), and then find the one whose "type" attribute is "submit" and whose "value" attribute is "Process" (see getAttribute in the documentation of HtmlElement).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking for, but it sounds to me like you're trying to get some sort of client-interaction emulation/automation.

Check out [Selenium's Java API](http://seleniumhq.org/)